# how to deploy Restful on Tomcat without IDE

Tags: eclipse, rest, maven, tomcat, server

I made `Restful` WS using `Eclipse` `Maven` `Tomcat7`,
and now i have an online `server` `Ubuntu` with `Tomcat7` on it.
what i need to know is how to deploy my `Restful` without  `Eclipse` and `Maven`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your tomcat7 installation directory is `~/Document/tomcat7` and you want to deploy `MyRestful.war`

1. copy `MyRestful.war` into directory `~/Document/tomcat7/webapps`
2. take a look at the file `~/Document/tomcat7/conf/server.xml` and find these lines

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Usually the port number is `8080` but it worth to double-check.

3. Now you can access the your Restful via

`http://your.server.url:8080/MyRestful/replace-with-your-rest-api`

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a `war`-file to a running Tomcat instance using the manager app in your browser. This is the URL: `http://your.server.intranet:8080/manager/html` (or `localhost:8080`).

It's necessary that the config file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/tomcat-users.xml` contains an admin user and an admin role. See [Configuring_Manager_Application_Access](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access)

Example:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
    <role rolename="manager-gui" />
    <role rolename="manager-script" />
    <role rolename="manager-jmx" />
    <role rolename="manager-status" />

    <user username="admin" password="whoknows" roles="manager-gui" />
    <user username="adminScript" password="topsecret" roles="manager-script" />
</tomcat-users>
```